# Cs cart didn't Upload Data or Export in Chrome 83

Tags: ajax, cs-cart

I can't upload files or download from Cscart Admin panel after update chrome to 83 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Kaiido says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62015090/5919562)   the problem is `src="javascript: false;` in Iframe for cs-cart you will found this code in this path `js\tygh\ajax.js` in tow different places at the file remove them and then delete your cache file you will found it here `var\cache\misc\statics\js\tygh` then refresh your browser

Answer (score 0):

Official solution to the problem:
How to Fix Admin Panel Issues in Google Chrome 83 on Old CS-Cart Versions?
https://www.cs-cart.com/blog/how-to-fix-admin-panel-issues-in-google-chrome-83-on-old-cs-cart-versions/